# Last used index from specific table

Tags: mysql, index, table, row

how can i take last used index from a specific table and add a +1 to it?

```
database login, table cars
```

I think i need to add it here ####

> $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$this->options['db_table']
>                   .'` (`carID`,`name`, `size`, `type`, `title`, `description`)'
>                   .' VALUES (#############,?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

Comment: Do you use MySQL?

Comment: What did you try? Did you read up on AUTO_INCREMENT ?

Comment: Yeah i did. But i'm new to programming so i prefer to ask + google and get more accurate information, then to just read and imagine something ;) I'm using xampp so it's a mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

The best way for that is to use the sequence way which is auto increment facility,  example:

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

so in that case you don't need to mention that id in the insert like:

```
INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES
    ('dog'),('cat'),('penguin'),
    ('lax'),('whale'),('ostrich');
```

also you can get the inserted id from the function

```
 LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

so here the id is auto last rec id + 1, you can see full reference about it from MySQL dev site:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: My search has ended up with something like this, but i'm using xammp so it's a mysqli and this code gives me errors: http://jsfiddle.net/aivaraspauga/sgurD/

Comment: could you check this link, it should help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535742/mysqli-auto-incremented-primary-id-that-was-generated